# Transfer Cassandra Table migration from Local Machine to server

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Currently I am working with DSE 4.8 version which installed into Virtual box in my laptop. In which I created a keyspace with class=SimpleStrategy and RF=3.
In this keyspace I have approx 15 tables with data. Currently having 1 datacenter named as Solr. 
Now I have to transfer into new server with 3 datacenter solr.
Can you suggest me steps to make it possible as implementation like production server. what will the required things which I have to do to make this possible? Please also check attached photos for reference. [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are looking for is SSTableLoader.  It is used to "Load existing SSTables into another cluster with a different number of nodes or replication strategy."

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html